# VB.net Receipt Printing to multiple thermal printers

Tags: vb.net, printing

I am looking for the best way to design and print POS receipts using VB.net. Basically I want the receipt to be printed to one printer and items to be printed to multiple kitchen thermal printers connected either directly or through network.

I've searched a lot and can't find the best approach to achieve this, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need the names of the printers you want to print to and just change them in code successevely like:

PrintDocument1.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "Printer Name"
 see at the link here:
http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1254639